# Typescript erase possibility of undefined or null

Tags: reactjs, typescript

So I have an input that returns an ISOString, and by default it receives the current date/time also in an ISOString. However when I assign the value to a variable using a ref, it tells me it could be undefined or null. I don't see how it can be.

My State

`const [date, setDate] = useState(new Date().toISOString())`

The ref:

`const dateRef = useRef<HTMLIonDatetimeElement>(null);`

The Input:

`<IonDatetime value={date} ref={dateRef} pickerFormat='DD MMMM YYYY HH:mm'displayFormat='DD MMM YYYY @ HH:mm' />`

How I'm putting the value in a variable:

`let deadline = dateRef.current!.value`
I used ! because it is always going to have a value

Comment: I assume it shows it on `deadline` variable? If so, try `dateRef.current?.value` instead

Comment: What's the question here? The ref types from React will always have a nullish default when not provided an initial value. You can either properly handle that edge case as @Lith suggests, or you can use the non-null assertion operator like you are currently.